# Morphia Aggregation Pipeline always returns the same data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have an item in a collection in MongoDB as follows:

```
{
"_id": "MY ID",
"myCollection": [{
    "code": "Código 1",
    "description": "Descripción entidad 1",
},
{
    "code": "Código 2",
    "description": "Descripción entidad 2",
},
{
    "code": "Código 3",
    "description": "Descripción entidad 3",
},
... follows to 19
```

If I use the AggregationPipeline like this:

```
AggregationPipeline pipeline = getDs().createAggregation(EntidadInfoEntity.class).unwind("myCollection")
    .sort(new Sort("myCollection.descripcion", 1)).limit(resultadosPorPagina);

Iterator<EntidadInfoEntity> resultado = pipeline.aggregate(EntidadInfoEntity.class);
    while (resultado.hasNext()) {
        EntidadInfoEntity entidadInfo = resultado.next();
    System.out.println(HerramientasJson.getInstance().convertirAJson(entidadInfo));
}
```

I get always the same result:

```
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 1","description":"Descripción entidad 1"}
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 1","description":"Descripción entidad 1"}
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 1","description":"Descripción entidad 1"}
```

Oddly, if I debug the pipeline I get this inside the "stages" value:

```
[{ "$unwind" : "$myCollection"}, { "$sort" : { "myCollection.description" : 1}}, { "$limit" : 25}]
```

And if I try to execute it directly under MongoDB shell with:

```
db.myEntities.aggregate([{ "$unwind" : "$myCollection"}, { "$sort" : { "myCollection.description" : 1}}, { "$limit" : 25}])
```

I get the correct result:

```
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 1","description":"Descripción entidad 1"}]}
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 2","description":"Descripción entidad 2"}]}
{"myCollection":[{"code":"Código 3","description":"Descripción entidad 3"}]}
```

Any ideas why could that be? Am I doing something wrong?

Best regards

Note: Some of the data has been rewritten to try to show the problem more clearly. Typing mistakes might occur, but the behaviour is as I explain.

Comment: Debugging inside Morphia, I found out this is due to the use of an internal cache in MorphiaIterator. It thinks it's the same object every time, and don't build a new one. I can't find a way to avoid using cache or to clear it. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

According to Morphia's team, the solution is to remove the "_id" field:

[Morphia Aggregation Pipeline always returns the same data #932](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/932)

And:

[Aggregation unwind function does not behave as expected? #854](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/854)

If you don't need the _id field it's fine. However, if you still need the _id field (my case), you'd need something else...